# I receive near "?": syntax error when try to execute Python3 Sqlite3 statment

Tags: python, database, sqlite

```
conn.execute("INSERT INTO USER_COUNT (AMOUNT_MESSAGES) VALUES  ?  WHERE USERNAME = ?", (count1, acc_name,))
```

I have this sqlite3 statement and I receive.

> near "?": syntax error

How to modify the statement to be okay.

Comment: conn.execute("INSERT INTO USER_COUNT (AMOUNT_MESSAGES) VALUES  (?) ", (count1,)); There is no WHERE clause in an INSERT maybe use UPDATE?

Comment: OK that not show the error but is not upadting the values also in this statment cursor.execute("INSERT INTO USER_COUNT VALUES (?, 0 );", (ACCOUNT_USERNAME,)) how to insert only unique values

Comment: Anyway I was quering wrong Thank you.